# C++ lexical analyzer

Tags: c++, lexical-analysis, lexical

I'm trying to write a small lexical analyzer and I have a small question

Consider the following string

```
cout << "hello world ;
```

Note that it doesn't have the `"` at the end.
Should I consider everything after the initial `"` a string and say there is a missing `"` at the end or ignore the initial `"` (saying that it doesn't end with another `"`) and procede to analyze the tokens `hello`, `world` till the end of the line?

Sorry if it seems a bit ambiguous.

Comment: What do you think?  Do you think it is necessary for you to tokenize `hello`, `world`, etc.?  Why would you require them?

Comment: If I was parsing the line I would do what other compilers do: generate an error that says "unterminated string constant"

Comment: Since it is unknown whether the intent was `"hello world";`, `"hello world ;";`, or any other possibility, it is my opinion that you must process the initial `"` and consume everything that follows until the terminating `"` is encountered (and in this case it was never encountered).

Comment: This is a syntax error in C++

Comment: @M.M. Iit is a lexical error in C++. It's defined in Chapter 2, *Lexical Conventions,* #2.13.4. Not a syntax error. Lexical analysis precedes parsing, and therefore syntax errors, by #2.1.7.

Comment: The important thing s that you should signal an error. Which one is less important, but the first option is both easier to program and results in less induced superfluous error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best way is to get Clang, compile your code and see what it will report you as errors. In the Clang source code you have two separate files containing all the possible lexical and parsing errors, so you can check if it report you a lexical or a parsing issue, no need to search each time in the thousands of pages of the C++ standard, Clang implements the standard :)